# Spring Boot + JWT Oauth2: Spring 5 vs Spring <5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, project-reactor

We have a project where we have:

```
+------------------------------------+
|                                    |    1. gets the token
|  Authorization Server (Auth)       | <------------------+
|   - spring-security-oauth2:2.0.14  |                    |
|                                    |                    |
+------------------------------------+                    +
                                                        user
                                                          +
+------------------------------------+                    |
|                                    |  2. uses the token |
|  Resource Server (RS)              |  to access resourcs|
|    - spring-security-oauth2:5.1.0  | <------------------+
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
```

We have been working in an environment **with no Webflux** and everything was working as expected. Worth mentioning that this JWT has the following claims: exp, user_name, authorities, jti, client_id, scope.

All the resources have an extra variable:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/car")
public SomeDto someResourceMethod(@PathVariable("id") CarId carId, Principal principal)
```

- In **"Spring Web"** (not using Reactor): The `Principal` is instantiated to `OAuth2Authentication` and there we have the operation `getName` on it.
- In **"Spring Webflux"** (using Reactor): The `Principal` is instantiated to `JwtAuthenticationToken` and we have now the `getSubject` operation, but it's null since the claim `sub` is null.

How do you think we should approach this? Create a new `JwtDecoder`? We are using Spring 5.1 and the decoder is `NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point, Reactive Resource Server supports JWT claims according to [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519), which is why you see the behavior change.

Yes, you can create your own decoder, which is probably the least invasive way:

```
public class CustomDecoder implements ReactiveJwtDecoder {
    private final ReactiveJwtDecoder nimbus;
    
    // ...

    public Mono<Jwt> decode(String token) {
        return this.nimbus.decode(token)
            .map(this::mapJwt);
    }

    private Jwt mapJwt(Jwt jwt) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = jwt.getClaims();
        // ... map claims accordingly
        return new Jwt(...);
    }
}
```

You may also be able to customize the authentication manager, which is [introduced in RC2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5750):

```
public class CustomReactiveAuthenticationManager
    implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {
    
    private final ReactiveAuthenticationManager delegate;

    // ...

    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        return this.delegate.authenticate(authentication)
            .map(this::mapAuthentication);
    }

    private Authentication mapAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
        // ... create a custom authentication where getName does what you need
    }
}
```

OR, if you are able to do some refactoring of your method signatures, then another option would be to use `@AuthenticatedPrincipal`:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/car")
public SomeDto someResourceMethod(
    @PathVariable("id") CarId carId,
    @AuthenticatedPrincipal Jwt jwt) {

    String name = jwt.getClaims().get("user_name");
    // ...
}
```

or perhaps more succinctly

```
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "getClaims().get('user_name')")
public @interface CurrentUsername {}    

@GetMapping("/{id}/car")
public SomeDto someResourceMethod(
    @PathVariable("id") CarId carId,
    @CurrentUsername String name) {

    // ...
}
```

You might also think about logging an enhancement on [Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues) to consider making the user attribute name configurable.

**EDIT**: I updated the EL expression since by default `@AuthenticatedPrincipal` calls `authentication.getPrincipal()` first.

**UPDATE**: In Spring Security 5.4+, the claim that holds the principal name is configurable, like so:

```java
@Bean
JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter =
        new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    authenticationConverter.setPrincipalClaimName("user_name");
    return authenticationConverter;
}
```

which then allows the OP to use `Principal#getName` as with the other principal types.

Comment: Thank you so much @jzheaux! Seriously perfect answer. I just get the error `"message": "EL1004E: Method call: Method getTokenAttributes() cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt"`. It's a matter of casting of the types I think. I fixed that using the expression: `getClaims().get('user_name').toString()`

What do you think?

Comment: For testing purposes in terms of the controller, we cannot use the @WithMockUser anymore because of the SEPL expression... instead we could use the `authentication` and create a JwtAuthenticationToken that is fine. Do you have any example of how to do this? Thank you so much.